# Hibernate Query com setParameters

Tags: java, sql, query, hibernate

O Hibernate está ignorando meus dados de um `Map` quando está nulo.

Se eu seto com `setParameter("nome",valor)` e o valor está nulo ele funciona, alguém sabe como resolver? Segue o código:

```
public List selectList(String sp, Map params, Class type) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    try {
        Query query;
        if (type != null) {
            query = session.createSQLQuery(strSelect + sp).addEntity(type).setProperties(params);
            session.clear();
            list = query.list();
            return list;
        } else {
            query = session.createSQLQuery(sp).setProperties(params);
            session.clear();
            list = query.list();
            return list;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return list;
    }
}
```

O erro:

> Grave:   org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have
>   been set: [oCodDep] [Select * From SP_CADDEP_SELECT_11(:oCodDep,
>   :oNomDep, null, null, null)]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:401)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:195)

No caso, o valor `sp` que estou passando como parâmetro seria esse:

```
"Select * From SP_CADDEP_SELECT_11(:oCodDep, :oNomDep, null, null, null)"
```

Eu tenho a opção de não passar o `oCodDep` nem o `oNomdep`, porém quando vai `null` o `setProperties` está ignorando.

Obs: não posso passar com `setParameter`.

Comment: Olá, Felipe! Não entendi bem. Quando você passa um valor nulo no Map o SQL funciona e o atributo é ignorado?

Comment: Quando eu passo um valor nulo no map , vamos fizer o parametro oCodDep , o sql nao funciona pq diz q esta faltando parametro 

"Not all named parameters have been set"

porem quando eu nao uso o setProperties e passo parametro por parametro com o setParameter ele funciona

Comment: Qual versão do Hibernate está usando?

Comment: Existem pelo menos [duas](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7705) [issues](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10796) relacionadas a isto. Ou seja, você provavelmente encontrou um bug no Hibernate. O problema está corrigido a partir da versão 5.1 do Hibernate. Sugiro experimentar uma versão com a correção e verificar se resolve seu problema.